# Move iTunes content from one machine to another

Tags: itunes, nas

I have moved my (smallish) iTunes library off my MacBookAir onto a NAS drive. This works fine. Now I want to move songs from my large iTunes library into the new library and just have one library shared across the two computers

I'm not afraid of the command line, but I wanted the easy way to do it.

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way to do this is with iTunes.

[Turn on Home Sharing for your iTunes account](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4620) and enable the feature in iTunes on your NAS-connected machine and on your machine you wish to use as a source for material to copy.

Start iTunes on both machines.

From the MacBook Air machine, look for your other iTunes library under the SHARED section in the left-hand list of iTunes. Select your other machine's library and expand the library contents. Select 'Music' to show all the music in that library:

[image: Home Sharing in iTunes]

Select all the music in that library by clicking on the top song in the list and pressing Cmd-A to select everything:

[image: Select All]

Now click the 'Import' button in the bottom right corner:

[image: Import it All]

iTunes will copy all the music from your large library in to your MacBook Air's library, storing the data on your NAS. You can speed the process along by doing the copy over a wired network connection instead of WiFi.

You can repeat this process for all content in the remote library, not just music.